# Overhead of saving results of a MySQL subquery into TEMPORARY TABLE (as opposed to duplicating the subquery)?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm writing a reporting library which provides a DSL for describing report logic in high-level terms, then compiles the resulting AST into SQL which is run against a MySQL database.

Sometimes the output contains duplicated subqueries. I'm thinking of making the compiler pull these duplicated subqueries into preceding `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT ...` statements, then reference the resulting temporary tables rather than running the same subqueries more than once.

Can anyone experienced with MySQL performance comment on whether this is likely to be an effective strategy? Once the results of a `SELECT` have been retrieved in memory, is there any significant overhead to saving those results in a temporary table?

Or will MySQL's query cache prevent identical subqueries from running more than once anyways?

**POSTSCRIPT:** I think in general, the amount of data our reports will work with is not enough to push temporary tables to disk. So, *assuming they can be held in memory*, is there a significant overhead to creating temporary tables?

Comment: I think it depends a lot on version of mysql, so you may want to consider restricting which versions of mysql your reporting library will work on (if you haven't already). My general understanding is MySQL subqueries are BAD and that conversion to actual joins or utilising a temp table is almost always better - unless the temp table gets pushed to disk! I would read the documentation mysql provide as a good starting point on the latest info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transformations.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-subqueries.html

Comment: That's an answer -- maybe not the only answer, but it would be worth posting as an answer (so I can upvote).

Comment: Glad to be of help, cheers for the upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends a lot on version of mysql, so you may want to consider restricting which versions of mysql your reporting library will work on (if you haven't already).

My general understanding is MySQL subqueries are BAD and that conversion to actual joins or utilising a temp table is almost always better - unless the temp table gets pushed to disk!

I would read the documentation mysql provide as a good starting point on the latest info: dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transformations.html and dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-subqueries.html